# Windows 7 rooted explorer registry hack

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, windows-registry

Have always used the following registry file to add a right click a rooted explorer here type entry for the windows explorer right click menu.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shell\Root Here]
@="Rooted Explorer"
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shell\Root Here\command]
@="%SystemRoot%explorer.exe /e,/root,%1"
```

It always worked great on windows XP but I haven't used it in a long time an when trying it out again I found that it does not work on windows 7. It looks like it is attempting to run the selected directory as an application.

Error message:

[image]

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Fix as in 'undo' or as in 'change the reg file so it works with win 7' ?

Comment: @Hennes: Fix it so that it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save the following as a .REG file and import:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shell\roothere]
@="Rooted E&xplorer"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shell\roothere\command]
@="explorer.exe /e,/root,\"%1\""
```

Comment: As easy as adding quotes and escaping them. Thanks. I tried extra quotes but not escaping them.